# Android Studio: Check if server socket is on/listening every X minutes

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp, ip

I'm making an Android app that checks every X minutes if a TCP/IP Server Socket has been opened on my computer. If SO, it does a connection and reads the data off it, if not, it waits and try's connecting again in X min...

**The code below works once when I turn the Server on first and then the client (manually) but I can't get the Client to keep checking if the Server Socket is on/listening based on time.** *Async approach won't work cause I can't put a delay in it and I can't get the Handler approach to work.*

**CheckserversocketeveryXmin.java**

```
public class AppListener extends Async {

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final int delay = 5000; //milliseconds

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            try {

                String msg_received = null;

                System.out.println("LISTENING FOR LAST INSTALLED APP");


                System.out.println("TRY");

                Socket socket = new Socket("85.190.178.23", 5050);

                // Get data sent through socket
                DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                System.out.println("DataInputStream Started");

                // read data that got sent
                msg_received = DIS.readUTF();

                System.out.println("Message from server" + msg_received);

                // Might not want to close socket, or only the first string will be sent and none after
                socket.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Did not receive string");
            }


            h.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);

}

}
```

Now I could be takling this wrong, putting this code into my main Activity, for some reason it trys every x seconds but never does the connection where as here it does the connection once if I remove the delay.

Would putting an infinite loop in a Async (I know that's not techincally good) and a wait/delay in it be a good approach? If so, do any of you have a pointer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Putting this code into my main Activity, for some reason it tries every x seconds but never does the connection

You are probably SDK 11+, so your handler is throwing a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` which you are swallowing in your catch block

> where as here it does the connection once if I remove the delay

You declare your `Handler` variable inside `handleMessage`, so after posting your runnable to the handle you immediately drop all references to it; it is probably being garbage collected. Make your two variables member variables in your `AppListener` class